# Jenkins Maven build: clean install != clean, install

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I am building Jenkins Maven project. In the Jenkinsfile if I use mvn clean pom.xml and mvn install pom.xml in separate lines, the build is successful. However , mvn clean install pom.xml fails.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you add the log with the error?

Comment: What exactly are the commands you enter? You should enter `mvn clean install`, not `mvn clean install pom.xml`.